# Check the directory for the database. [ Path = \E:\NEW.sdf ]

Tags: c#, database, windows, sdf

Actually i am connecting with database in a Windows Mobile 6.5 Device, i Try to Open the connection then it tell the error The path is not valid. Check the directory for the database. [ Path = \E:\NEW.sdf ] Request to help me in this regards, Goran Ghafoor

Comment: Do you have any code leading up to this point that is not functioning? If the path isn't valid, it is entirely possible that you forgot to plug in the device to start with.

Answer (score 0):

There are no drive letters on a Windows Mobile device, you would use a path like:

\Program Files\MyApp\new.sdf